# Twilio API get SID of given number

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I need to get SID of given number via API.

I am using this code and it works:

```
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "PhoneNumber" => $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
    )) as $number
) {
    $sid = $number->sid;
}
```

My question is I do not need this to be in a loop since there will only ever be one entry, so what is the singular of `->getIterator`? I could use `->get` but that requires the SID, which I don't have yet.

Answer (score 1):

Megan from Twilio here.

In order to receive the Sid you must do within the loop. Here's an example from the [incoming phone numbers API reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#instance) as you also show above.

```
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers->getIterator(0, 50, array(
         "PhoneNumber" => "+15555555555"
    )) as $number
) {
   echo $number->sid;
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That gives the SID, what is the method to use PhoneNumber instead? I found the solution but the solution uses loops which I don't require, and removing the loop breaks it since ->get expects a SID apparently.

Comment: Updating my answer. You do have to use the loop. Which seems initially weird especially given the comment //If you do not have a sid,
// check out the list resource examples on this page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have a totally different version of the php library.  But the above didn't work at all for me.

I ended up accomplishing it like this...

```
$phoneNumber="+15551234567";

$twilio=new Client(TWILIO_ACC_ID,TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

//get all the phone numbers on our account (assuming we won't have more than 1000 numbers)
$incoming_phone_numbers=$twilio->incomingPhoneNumbers->read([],1000);

//look for the one with our matching number and save the sid
foreach ($incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    if ($number->phoneNumber==$phoneNumber) {
        $thisSid=$number->sid;
        break;
    }
}

if ($thisSid) print("Found the SID for: ".$phoneNumber."  It's: ".$thisSid);
```